# Confusion in code using inheritance, instantiation, *args, **kwargs

Tags: python, class

```
class Pen(object):
    def __init__(self, mean_radius = None, length = None):
        self.usage = "Is used to apply ink trails to drawing surfaces"
        self.mean_radius = mean_radius
        self.length = length

class FountainPen(Pen):
    def __init__(self, manufacturer = "Waterman", *args, **kwargs):
        Pen.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.manufacturer = manufacturer
        self.cartridge_state =  "non-empty"

>>> instance_FP = FountainPen(5, 1)
>>> instance_FP.mean_radius
>>> print instance_FP.mean_radius
1    
>>> print instance_FP.length
None
```

What happens with the integer `5` being passed as an argument in the instantiation of `FountainPen`?
Why does `print instance_FP.mean_radius` return `1` and not `5`?

Comment: "What happens..." Did it occur to you to try looking at the other attributes of the instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to think it like that: `*args` and `**kwargs` "eat" all the positional/keyword arguments left by the "regular" arguments that precede them. If you put them in the end, they will only get whatever couldn't fit the "regular arguments".

So, when you write `FountainPen(5,1)` what happens is that `FountainPen.__init__` gets called like this:

- `self` is set to the newly created instance;
- `manufacturer` gets the first argument, which is 5;
- `*args` "eats" all the remaining positional arguments, i.e. just `1`; so `args` is now set to `[1]`;
- `*kwargs` would eat any keyword argument left, but there's none, so it becomes `{}`.

It's then clear that `Pen.__init__` is called with just `1` as argument (besides `self`), and `length` remains set to its default value (`None`).

Answer (score 2):

[Matteo Italia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177278/246207)'s mentions what is wrong, basically `manufacturer` is a positional argument. You can fix it by slightly changing `FountainPen`'s `__init__` to the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, manufacturer = "Waterman", **kwargs):
```

Doing this will make `manufacturer` a keyword argument so to change it you will have to call:

```
FountainPen(manufacturer="newval")
```

Note: Unfortunately this syntax (of having keyword only arguments after the `*args` parameter) is only valid in Python 3. Jon Clements has a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11177313/246207) that solves this problem for Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant solution would be:

```
class FountainPen(Pen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Pen.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.manufacturer = kwargs.get('manufacturer', 'Waterman')
        self.cartridge_state =  "non-empty"

blah = FountainPen(5, 1, manufacturer='Waterman')
```

Comment: This can get fixed up a bit better if you want to maintain the behaviour of the default value. Use: `self.manufacturer = kwargs.get('manufacturer', "Waterman")`

Comment: @JPvdMerwe Very good point - didn't think of that! Post edited to reflect your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In your code 5 is assigned to the argument `manufacturer` and 1 goes to `*args`.

When passing arguments without keys to a function, you must first provide the explicit ones. The rest is passed to *args. To avoid this, provide keywords when calling your constructor:

```
>>> instance_FP = FountainPen(mean_radius=5, length=1)
```